# How to use FluentMigrator.Runner for selected type of database only

Tags: c#, fluent-migrator

Currently when I add **FluentMigrator.Runner** nuget package into c# project it automatically installs all other related nuget packages: **FluentMigrator.Runner.Db2**, **FluentMigrator.Runner.Firebird**, etc.

But I only need SqlServer support. I can't uninstall all this secondary packages because FluentMigrator.Runner depends on them.

If I force remove references I just got runtime errors:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'FluentMigrator.Runner.Db2, Version=3.0.0.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aacfc7de5acabf05' or one of its dependencies. 
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

This makes my c# project to reference a lot of useless dlls. Especially Sql Server Ce native files.
Is there a way to get rid of Db2, Firebird and other implementations if I only need SqlServer?

I use Fluent Migrator version 3 and .Net 4.7.1

Comment: I'd like to know the answer to this question as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround to this problem:

1. Remove project references to the other database runners;
2. Remove entries for the other database runners in the "packages.config" file;
3. Delete all files for the other database runners in the "packages" folder for the solution;
4. Remove these lines from the .csproj file with Notepad:

```html
<Import Project="..\packages\FluentMigrator.Runner.SqlServerCe.3.1.3\build\netstandard2.0\FluentMigrator.Runner.SqlServerCe.targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages\FluentMigrator.Runner.SqlServerCe.3.1.3\build\netstandard2.0\FluentMigrator.Runner.SqlServerCe.targets')" />
  <Target Name="EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <ErrorText>This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is {0}.</ErrorText>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\FluentMigrator.Runner.SqlServerCe.3.1.3\build\netstandard2.0\FluentMigrator.Runner.SqlServerCe.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\packages\FluentMigrator.Runner.SqlServerCe.3.1.3\build\netstandard2.0\FluentMigrator.Runner.SqlServerCe.targets'))" />
  </Target>
```

Comment: Funnily removing unwanted targets and references is the only way that I found myself. Such a bizarre dependency structure. `Fluentmigrator.Runner` depends on all other db types. A bit confusing.